# Segmentation fault when using fork() in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fork

Basically what i'm trying to do is read a number from a file, increment the value by one, and then write the number back to the same file. Using fork() is supposed to have both processes accessing the file but using locks so they take turns. I keep getting a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void appendValue(FILE *, int *);
int readValue(FILE *, int *);
void lockFile(FILE *);
void unlockFile(FILE *);
void whatProcess(pid_t *pID);

int main(void) {
    pid_t pID;
    pID = fork();
    int value = 0, counter = 0;
    int *valPtr = &value;
    pid_t *pidPtr = &pID;
    FILE *file = fopen("output.txt", "a+");
    lockFile(file);

    while(counter < 1000) {
        whatProcess(pidPtr);
        value = readValue(file, valPtr);
        value++;
        appendValue(file, valPtr);
        rewind(file);
        counter++;
    }
    unlockFile(file);       
    fclose(file);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void whatProcess(pid_t *pID) {
    if(*pID > 0) {
        printf("\n --- In Parent ---");
    } else if(*pID == 0) {
        printf("\n --- In Child ---");
    } else {
            printf("\n --- fork() Failed ---");
    }
}

void lockFile(FILE *file) {
    int lock;
    lock = lockf(fileno(file), F_LOCK, 0);
        while(lock != 0) {}
        if(lock == 0) {
            printf("\nPID %d: Lock Successful", getpid());
        } else {
            printf("\nPID %d: Lock Unsuccessful", getpid());
        }   
}

void unlockFile(FILE *file) {
    int lock;
    lock = lockf(fileno(file), F_LOCK, 0);
        while(lock != 0) {}
        if(lock == 0) {
            printf("\nPID %d: Unlock Successful", getpid());
        } else {
            printf("\nPID %d: Unlock Unsuccessful", getpid());
        }   
}

void appendValue(FILE *file, int *value) {
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", *value);
}

int readValue(FILE *file, int *value) {
    while(!feof(file)) {
        fscanf(file, "%d", value);
    }
    return *value;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? In which line do you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: What would you suggest for a debugger?

Comment: My guess is the `fscanf` in `readValue`.  You don't need the *address of* operator there

Comment: @user1545867: Good tools are the GNU debugger (gdb) and valgrind.

Comment: What's your compiler? If you use `gcc`, you can debug with `gdb`. Make sure you give `-g` to `gcc`.

Comment: Oh and yes, definitely valgrind.

Comment: I'll buck the curve and recommend simply reading the code.  Debuggers and static/runtime validation tools are incredibly useful but should not be the first thing you grab.  Read the code.  Look at the logs.  Fix your code until it compiles *without warnings*.  Run validation tools regularly (e.g., lint).  Then use a debugger if you still need one.

Comment: @D.Shawley, compilers warnings are also kind of output from a validation tool, and you look at them right from the start. It's not so black and white, although I agree that being able to understand the code is important.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I ended up using a debugger (gdb), but I do understand why I was getting a segmentation fault. I have updated the code to my final working set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fscanf` in `readValue` is writing to a non-allocated location.  You are passing `value` in as a pointer so there is no need to use the address of operator.

```
int readValue(FILE *file, int *value) {
    fscanf(file, "%d", value);
    printf("\nreadValue(): %d", *value);
    return *value;
}
```

Or, even better:

```
int readValue(FILE *file, int *value) {
    if (fscanf(file, "%d", value) == 1) {
        printf("\nreadValue(): %d", *value);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Your current function does not indicate whether it has succeeded or failed.  Either add a status return value (zero, -1 are pretty common) or omit error checking and do this instead:

```
int readValue(FILE *file) {
    int buf;
    if (fscanf(file, "%d", &buf) == 1) {
        printf("\nreadValue(): %d", buf);
    } else {
        perror("readValue(): fscanf failed");
    }
    return buf; /* could be a garbage value, use at own risk */
}
```